# Visual Studio: Chart Area LABEL DATA

Tags: visual-studio-2008

How to show LABEL DATA on Chart Area?

Comment: Are you talking about the Chart control?

Comment: Yes Neil the Properties of ChartArea.  thank u

Answer (score 0):

On Properties
Go to Series and click on Collection
From Series Collection Editor click on Label {IsValueShownAsLabel} change to 'True'

*.*'